# Why doesn't overflow-y work on a mobile?

Tags: android, css, html, mobile

I have CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #creating_products {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="creating_products">
   <div id="product_fields">
      <ul id="sortable_invoice_products">
          {section name=foo start=1 loop=11 step=1}
              <div class="invoice_margin_template"></div>
              <li class="ui-sortable-handle invoice_sortable">
                   <div class="product_fields_parent">
                       ........
                   </div>
               </li>
          {/section}
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I tested this code on my Android, part of the "creating_products" div was hidden, but my scroll bar did not appear. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your html is broken and desktop browsers are fixing it on the fly?
Try to remove the `<div class="invoice_margin_template"></div>` inside the `<ul>` tag and make sure the html inside the `<li>` is valid

```css
body{
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #creating_products {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="creating_products">
  <div id="product_fields">
    <ul id="sortable_invoice_products">
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle invoice_sortable">
        <div class="product_fields_parent"></div>
        some content
      </li>
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle invoice_sortable">
        <div class="product_fields_parent"></div>
        some content
      </li>
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle invoice_sortable">
        <div class="product_fields_parent"></div>
        some content
      </li><li class="ui-sortable-handle invoice_sortable">
        <div class="product_fields_parent"></div>
        some content
      </li>
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle invoice_sortable">
        <div class="product_fields_parent"></div>
        some content
      </li>
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle invoice_sortable">
        <div class="product_fields_parent"></div>
        some content
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, mostly scroll appears when you want to scroll an area. See if the text is not cutting from down. Again touch the area and try to scroll up. It is because in android scroll doesn't show when a CSS `overflow` has been implemented.

Second thing, use `height` in place of `max-height`. Try this and see if it would help you. Sometimes `max-height` doesn't work.

Also you add `overflow-x:hidden;`

May these simple changes works for you.

Thanks